# Demo Cards are not showing up on Android Wear Emulator

Tags: wear-os

Android Wear App on my handset keeps asking me to "Please upgrade Google Search and reinstall Android Wear" though everything is updated already.

I'm able to connect my handset (4.3) to emulator, though Demo Cards on Android Wear App are not being shown on the wearable. What could be the issue?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the instructions here http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html to get the latest version of Google Play Services. You need to opt-in and then download the latest versions of all three packages (Google Play Services, Google Search, Android Wear Companion) in the provided order for this to work properly. These steps are only necessary while Google Play Services is rolling out, and in a few weeks will become unnecessary.

Comment: Google Search needed an update. Though it was shown as installed but there was an update which was made available probably after I opt-in.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Opting in to the group ensures that you get the latest version immediately, instead of waiting for the rollout to complete. So you need to do the update since your phone already has older versions of these applications installed.

Comment: The Google Play Services 5.0 rollout has completed http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html, so these instructions will no longer be needed. The Android Wear app is now visible in the Play Store at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app